# There's any way to put an image from a string (with the contents of an image) in html?

Tags: php, html, image

So what I want to do is to write a txt with text and image contents, and then put it in a webpage from the string (with php).

Read the file with php and get a line of the content of the txt to transform it to an image and be able to put it on an html  tag.

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't really know how to do this, or even if it's possible.

Possible duplicate: I think that it isn't because I didn't know what Base64 was so that other answer you were supposed to know it, so for doing it easier to search for people I think it's better to leave it (or not I don't really care so much).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: thanks! I'll try it

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but you can take the contents of a image file for example and base64 encode it and put that directly in the `<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgo ..." >` tag.  This link is to the answer (for the duplicate, I posted) that is specific to PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html#answer-21606233

Comment: "Read the file with php and get a line of the content of the txt to transform it to an image and be able to put it on an html tag." - so you want to generate images on the fly that simply contain your lines of text from the file? Perhaps as a anti-copy/paste measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php:

```
$path = <path to file>;

echo '<img src="data:' . mime_content_type($path) . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))" alt="alt_text">';
```

html:

`<img src="data:<mime>;base64,<base64 byte data string>" alt="alt_text">`

you can set an image tag to hold raw image byte data, it just has to be in base64 format.

the `data:<mime>;` part holds the mime, or file content type.

the `base64,<base64 encoded string>` holds the raw data from the image that you get from using `file_get_contents($path)` and then encoded in base64 format with `base64_encode()` function